# Elegir varios RadioButtons y que se guarden en mi base de datos MYsql

Tags: java

¿Cómo hago para que al seleccionar varios `radiobutton` y guardarlos, estos se muestren en la base de datos?

Al seleccionar varios `radiobutton` solo y guardarlos en la base de datos, solo sale el último `radiobutton` que seleccioné.

```
public String enfer;
   private void rbHTAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    enfer="HTA";
}                                     

private void rbECVActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    enfer="ECV";
}                                     

private void rbDMActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
   enfer="DM";
}                                    

private void rbCardiopatiasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
   enfer="Cardiopatías";
}                                              

private void rbSindromedemeniereActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
   enfer="Sindrome de meniére";
}                                                   

private void rbParalisisActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
   enfer="Paralisis Facial";
}                                           

private void rbLaberintitisActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
   enfer="Laberintitis";
}                                              

private void rbNingunoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   enfer="Ninguno";
} 


void agregarpac(){

    p.setEnfermedades(enfer);
    
    if(pac.agregarPaciente(p)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos guardados");
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
    }
```

Comment: La última pregunta que has hecho debe ir como nueva pregunta (sin olvidar mostrar lo que intentaste hasta el momento). Por cierto, el IDE que estás utilizando (Netbeans en este caso) es irrelevante en la pregunta. Lee [ask].

Comment: Deja ver lo que estás intentando; las preguntas que solo tienen instrucciones, en su mayoría, no son bien recibidas ni contestadas.